# How am I supposed to fix this utf-8 encoding error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-3.6

So, I have non-binary strings like this one, which encoding is broken:

> La funci\xc3\xb3n est\xc3\xa1ndar datetime. datetime. now() retorna la fecha y hora actual.

This string should look like this:

> La función estándar datetime. datetime. now() retorna la fecha y hora actual.

In interactive console, it's way easy to fix: just like this:

```
>>> b'La funci\xc3\xb3n est\xc3\xa1ndar datetime. datetime. now() retorna la fecha y hora actual.'.decode('utf-8')
```

**This would output the string correctly decoded. However, in the script I am trying to build, this string is like you see it in the first example, but unicode, not binary.**

I have tried every trick my mind could come with (except hardcoding an equivalence dictionary and using it with `replace()`, which I'd rather not do if I can help it): the most crazy thing I tried was:

```
# Just to clarify the format of the broken strings, I declare this one here
broken_string = 'La funci\\xc3\\xb3n est\\xc3\\xa1ndar datetime. datetime. now() retorna la fecha y hora actual.'

match = re.findall(r'\\x[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]', broken_string)
for e in match:
    broken_string = str(broken_string.encode().replace( e.encode(), str(chr(int(e[-2:], 16))).encode() ))
```

Well, actually this loop ended up messing the string even worse :-$

This monstruous train wreck is just the wildest idea I could show to you. Actually, I have tried so many things already that I don't remember them all. But you will probably see my intent here.

It's actually hilarious that I can't seem to solve this in an elegant way, without having to hardcode a dictionary of this style for using with  `str.replace()` in a loop:

```
dict_for_fix = {
    '\\xc3\\xb3' : b'\xc3\xb3'.decode('utf-8'),
    # I mean, I would have to brute-force hardcode lots of combinations this way...
}
```

This just blew my mind. Isn't there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: If you `print(my_str[8:11])` what do you get back?

Comment: I get `\xc`. Does this clarify anything?

Comment: Doing `broken_string.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` may in fact be what you want.

Comment: Interesting: I tried something like: `broken_string.encode(ascii).decode('utf-8)` or something like that, I don't remember... and variants with latin1, to no avail. Maybe your combination is what I need? I'mma try it out

Comment: It works!! It works indeed!!! Thank you... I have wasted two, three or more hours trying to figure it out... you indeed spared me of more hours of pain. I didn't knew that 'unicode_escape' existed at all. **You can go ahead and post that as the answer :-)**

Comment: @metatoaster I see what you did there, that was a lot of non-obvious steps to go through.  Definitely worthy of turning into a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying to detangle a string that has doubly encoded sequences that was intended to be an escape sequence (i.e. `\\` instead of `\`), the special [text encoding codec `unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) may be used to rectify them back to the expected entity for further processing.  However, given that the input is already of the type `str`, it needs to be turned into a `bytes` - assuming that the entire string is of fully valid `ascii` code points, that may be the codec for the initial conversion of the initial `str` input into `bytes`.  The `utf8` codec may be used should there are standard unicode codepoints represented inside the `str`, as the `unicode_escape` sequences wouldn't affect those codepoints.  Examples:

```
>>> broken_string = 'La funci\\xc3\\xb3n est\\xc3\\xa1ndar datetime.'
>>> broken_string2 = 'La funci\\xc3\\xb3n estándar datetime.'
>>> broken_string.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
'La funciÃ³n estÃ¡ndar datetime.'
>>> broken_string2.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
'La funciÃ³n estÃ¡ndar datetime.'
```

Given the assumption that the `unicode_escape` codec assumes decoding to `latin1`, this intermediate string may simply be encoded to `bytes` using the `latin1` codec post decoding, before turning that back into unicode `str` type through the `utf8` (or whatever appropriate target) codec:

```
>>> broken_string.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'La función estándar datetime.'
>>> broken_string2.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'La función estándar datetime.'
```

As requested, an addendum to clarify the partially messed up string. Note that attempting to decode `broken_string2` using the `ascii` codec will not work, due to the presence of the unescaped `á` character.

```
>>> broken_string2.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe1' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I just noticed something following your new examples: if I used the combination you show me on the question's comment (that you not included in the final answer, but I edited it for the sake of completeness), if I used it on `broken_string2`, it would crash like `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe1' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)`. **If you didn't develop the final answer, I wouldn't even consider strings that are partially (but not completely) corrupted.** Good point

Comment: @SebasSBM Yeah, that `broken_string2` contains non-ascii codepoint `á` - hence it cannot be encoded as `ascii`.  Also I copy-pasted the wrong line while I was testing, I had intended to encode as `ascii` (instead of `latin1`) on the original input to demonstrate the original statement as written in the introduction.

Comment: The reason `latin1` works so well is that it's the *only* encoding that has a 1:1 correspondence between codepoint values from 0-255 and byte values.  It's a handy trick to know about.